# Java threads.. cuasing the thread to terminate after a set time

Tags: java, multithreading, thread-safety

I have written some code that submits a callable to an executor, storing the future in a map against an id. In the call method I wait for a flag to be set before proceeding. Basically I need to wait for an external operation to return to me and say we are done - here is the data and now you can continue... I dont think what I have is correct:

```
public class MyClass implements Callable<Boolean> {

    ---
    ---
    private boolean done = false;

    @override
    public Boolean call() {

        --  wait for flag to be set...
        //continue....
    }

}
```

--main code--

```
//create the above class..

//submit it...

//get the future store in map...

//-- wait for response from external application...

///tie it up with an id

//set the attribute so the callable can continue and complete..
```

Questions:

1. The above will not work as I am returned a Future and not the object. I was thinking of maybe creating a new interface which inherits from the callable class - does that make sense?
2. I need the thread to wait and then die if no response is received. Is it possible to set that on a thread at all?

Answer (score 3):

You can schedule a task which will cancel the waiting task. When the waiting task finishes it can cancel the scheduled task. (which ever finished first will cancel the other)

This assumes you have a task which is interruptible in the first place.

Comment: I just want to point out to @lqbal that it is not trivial to make a task interruptible and that he should probably read up on multi-threading.

Answer (score 0):

there is a wait(long timeout) function available..  heres some documentation on it

http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/lang/Object.html

with this wait(long timeout) function, the thread will wait until it gets a notify() (or notifyAll()) OR until the timout expires.

any of the following will break the wait();

1. notify();
2. notifyAll();
3. timout gets reached

Answer (score 0):

Use the [`Future#get(long, TimeUnit)`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/Future.html#get%28long,%20java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit%29).

This will wait for some time for an answer, and throw a [`TimeoutException`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/TimeoutException.html) if there is no return value in the given period. Then just catch the exception and let the thread finish grafefully.

Comment: Yeap i understand that, but how can i re-start the thread that is waiting to run..

Comment: You don't. Once the thread is finished, you just create another one giving it the same runnable.

Comment: But if my callable is waiting on something external to occur, then my future object, is still in wait state... how can i re-trigger it to start again... i was trying to use a flag..

Comment: OK, so just use [`Object#wait()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Object.html#wait%28%29) in your `call()` method, and [`Object#notify()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Object.html#notify%28%29) in whatever code you are waiting to finish.

Comment: cant really see how that would be possible.. if in my call method i set this.wait()... then in my  ain thread i only have my future object, from which i cannot re-start this thread... humm... maybe using futures is not the way...